# how get text with break line from element (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, element, line-breaks

All!

I need to get the text from the element wit break lines. When I use the text() jQuery command, I get the text without break lines. However, in the properties (innerText, outerText) of the elements, I see the currect text.

For example:

```
<table><tr><td id = 'element'>word#1<br>word#2</td></tr></table>
```

Properties (in command line in Chrome) I see:

```
innerText: word#1 -> word#2
outerText: word#1 -> word#2
```

where -> - break line

But when I use text(), I get

```
word#1word#2
```

Tell me please how currect get text with break line

Comment: use `.html()` to get `<br>`

Comment: Why not just select the `br` elements? `$('#element br')`?

Comment: "You need to get via .html()"

Sorrt, but no :( Because if 

<span style = "color: red;">word</div>#1<br>word#2

.html() will return too much extra text

Answer (score 4):

You need to get via `.html()` to get also the `<br>`s. After it you can replace the `<br>`'s with `break lines`.

Consider you already has the text with `<br>`'s. Split it with `<br>` and join with `\n`.

```js
var text = "asd<br>asd<br>asd";
console.log(text);
var withBreakLines = text.split('<br>').join('\n');
console.log(withBreakLines);
```